# Google MAP api v3 and autocomplete jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, autocomplete

I'm trying to add a simple auto-complete input text with jQuery and Google Map V3, for the city, here is my HTML code to insert the search field;

```
<input id="places" class="ui-bar-d ui-input-text ui-body-null ui-shadow-inset ui-body-d ui-autocomplete-input ui-corner-all" placeholder="Which city ?" data-type="search">
```

I followed the code source of this page: [Jquery mobile with Google map v3](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn-history/r248/trunk/demos/jquery-mobile-google-maps-places.html)

I added this code in an external JS file:

```
$(function() {

function PlacesSearchControl(str) {
    var el = document.createElement('DIV');
    var wrap = document.createElement('DIV');
    var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
    el.appendChild(wrap);
    wrap.appendChild(input);
    $(el).attr('id', 'control');
    $(input).addClass('ui-bar-d ui-input-text ui-body-null ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-body-d ui-autocomplete-input');
    $(input).attr('id', 'places');
    $(input).val(str);
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('autocomplete', input, function(ui) {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('set', 'bounds', null);
        $.mobile.pageLoading();
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('placesSearch', { 'location': ui.item.position, 'radius': '5000'/*, 'name': ['store']*/ }, function(results, status) {
            if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                $.each(results, function(i, item) {
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'id': item.id, /*'icon': item.icon,*/ 'position': item.geometry.location, 'bounds':true }).click(function() {
                        $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': '<h4>'+item.name+'</h4>'}, this);
                    });
                });
            }
            $.mobile.pageLoading(true);
        });
    });
    $(input).focus(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() === str ) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    }).blur(function() {
            if ( $(this).val() == '' ) {
                $(this).val(str);
            }
        });
    return el;
}

$('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': '58.00, 12.00', 'zoom': 3, 'disableDefaultUI': true, 'mapTypeId': 'roadmap'}).bind('init', function(event, map) {
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addControl', new PlacesSearchControl('Search places...'), 1);
});

});
```

When I'm trying to hit a city in my input text field, nothing happens, can someone help me to find out what's wrong in my code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: got any errors in your console?

Comment: Hi Chanckjh, thanks for your interest, here is the Debug console result:http://pastie.org/8073876

Comment: This link : pastie.org/8073876

Comment: thats not the console. right click > inspect element > choose tab Console.

Comment: Thanks but it's exactly what I've done on this web link

Comment: @Katcha It would be better if you create a jsfiddle of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Throughout your `Javascript`, you've used an ID called **map_canvas**,
>   but the element is not there in your `HTML` code.  If you've already have that `HTML` code,  then I'm sure you're not using properly using the scripts.

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('autocomplete', input, function(ui) {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('set', 'bounds', null);
        $.mobile.pageLoading();
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('placesSearch', { 'location': ui.item.position, 'radius': '5000'/*, 'name': ['store']*/ }, function(results, status) {
            if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                $.each(results, function(i, item) {
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'id': item.id, /*'icon': item.icon,*/ 'position': item.geometry.location, 'bounds':true }).click(function() {
                        $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': '<h4>'+item.name+'</h4>'}, this);
                    });
                });
            }
            $.mobile.pageLoading(true);
        });
    });
```

- You've have copy pasted the entire code used in the example, there
  lies the problem.  My guess is that you're trying to have `only the
  search textBox`.  If so check this
  [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/moinsam/SDPHm/).
- If you are trying to have `autocomplete with textbox`, then based on
  the example  I've made an
  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/XgsC6/31/) in JSFiddle.

Hope you understood.

Comment: @Katcha I'm glad I was able to help.